# Call webservice from batch file calling in scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, asmx, credentials

It's several days I search for a problem. I've create an Intranet (Authenticate mode windows allow member of domain)  and I a webservice can be called by asmx file
I create a bat file to be use in scheduled task

```
@echo off

start /MIN iexplore.exe http://server/WS.asmx/Importation
Timeout /T 80 /NoBreak>NUL

taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
```

Until now it was good. But from severals days now I don't see the calling asmx correctly (I create a log file and it's empty.
When I call this WebService from my Intranet : it's Ok
I notice now when I run my batch file manually it's ask me a username and password
I look several sample but don't find the good option.
Why Ask me a password when my task have the goods credentials. And How open this asmx with a username/password from scheduler?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way...
In Internet option u have a checkbox "activate the protected mode" uncheck it
And I add my Intranet to Intranet Site
Like this server isn't use directly (only resquest by Excel) and like it's inside protected struture. The risk are very limited.
I hope that can help